# mockk, clearAllMocks or unmockkAll

Tags: kotlin, mockk

mockk 1.9.3

In the test noticed if did static mock in previous test, the next test will be using same mock.
Thought to do a reset at @After, but not sure which one to use clearAllMocks or unmockkAll.

in https://mockk.io/

```
unmockkAll  unmocks object, static and constructor mocks
clearAllMocks   clears regular, object, static and constructor mocks
```

but not clear what are the difference by `unmocks` and `clears`.

e.g.

```
@Test
fun test_1() {
    mockkStatic(TextUtils::class)
    every { TextUtils.isEmpty(param } returns true

    //test
    doSomeThingUsingTextUtils()
    // verify
    ... ...
}
@Test
fun test_2() {
    // in this test it does not want the mocked stub behavior

}
```

What it should use, `clear` or 'unmock`?

Answer (score 4):

For me, understanding the **difference** between `Clearing and Unmocking` was sufficient.

> **clear** - deletes internal state of objects associated with mock
> resulting in empty object
>
> **unmock** - re-assigns transformation of
> classes back to original state prior to mock
> ([Source](https://mockk.io/#clearing-vs-unmocking))

PS: [I understand the confusion! I had it as well!](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/184)

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: thx! but not sure what the difference of these two. I updated the question with a sample.

Answer (score 2):

`clearAllMocks()` will undo `every { TextUtils.isEmpty(param } returns true`.

while `unmockkAll()` will undo `mockkStatic(TextUtils::class)`